# Installing .pkg: determining if the app being updated is presently running?

Tags: macos, package, installation, pkgbuild

I'm using the brilliant Mac OS X "Packages" to generate an install a .pkg, and wondered how one constructs a shell script to make sure the application file being updated over isn't presently running (which would seem like a Very Bad Idea).

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be handled by using a `pre-install` script, or `installer plug-in`. It's unclear what you plan on doing though if the application is running.

Comment: Yes, I get that I can handle it during the pre-install script.  I'd like to simple notify the user that they need to "quit" the app.  I've noticed a number of installers do this: for example, some installers will NOT permit Xcode to be running during the install.  What I'm looking for is: how do I accurately detect the app is running, and how can I put up an alert from inside a shell script?

Comment: You can't really alert someone strictly through a shell script since the installer is using it's own gui; returning any type of alert or secondary screen with information would require creating an installer plug-in. Doing that should allow you to check if the process is running likely via `NSTask` and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: I'm wondering if this can now be handled by the "Distribution Definition XML Schema", which defines the structure of distribution.dist and includes an "app" field that "Identifies an application that must be closed before the package is installed.":    https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/DistributionDefinitionRef/Chapters/Distribution_XML_Ref.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005370-CH100-SW21

Comment: @SMGreenfield: Yes that would work also if you just want that behavior to happen; If you a running something without a bundle identifier though (such as a background process) it might not work.